# Substitute values from one data-frame to another

Tags: r

I have two data frames, A and B, constructed by exporting csv data, that can be resume as following (very simplified):

`dataA <- read.csv2("dataA.csv", header = TRUE))`

```
#       Name        DataA_1     DataA_2     DataA_3       DataA_4        
#        1            4            5            6            5                        
#        2            7            5            6            4                       
#        3            6            5            5            4                        
#        4            3            3            3            4                        
#        5            1            2            4            3
```

`dataB <- read.csv2("dataB.csv", header = TRUE)`

```
#     DataB_1  DataB_2  DataB_3  DataB_4 
#      1        8        3        5
```

All I want to do is to substitute all values in data frame A (except the first column) that are above a certain quantity, let's say 4, by the value corresponding to the same column in data frame B. For exemple, since `DataA_2` is 5 for te 2nd person (element (2,2) in A) , I want to replace it by the `DataB_2` of data frame B, that is 8. The final result should look like this:

```
#       Name        DataA_1     DataA_2     DataA_3       DataA_4        
#        1            4            8            3            5                        
#        2            1            8            3            4                       
#        3            1            8            3            4                        
#        4            3            3            3            4                        
#        5            1            2            2            3
```

I already fund a way to do it by constructing an algorithm with a loop, but I'm not satisfied by this solution, since I want to have something shorter and faster. I'm petty sure that it is possible to do with a function like `transmute` in `library(dplyr)`, but I'm unable to find a solution. If somebody knows how to do it with `transmute` or another function please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option

```
dataA[-1] <- (dataA[-1] <= 4) * dataA[-1] + (dataA[-1] > 4) * dataB[rep(1, nrow(dataA)), ]
```

gives

```
> dataA
  Name DataA_1 DataA_2 DataA_3 DataA_4
1    1       4       8       3       5
2    2       1       8       3       4
3    3       1       8       3       4
4    4       3       3       3       4
5    5       1       2       4       3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical index and use that to subset the replace the values

```
i1 <- dataA[-1] > 4
dataA[-1][i1] <- dataB[col(dataA[-1])][i1]
```

-output

```
dataA
#  Name DataA_1 DataA_2 DataA_3 DataA_4
#1    1       4       8       3       5
#2    2       1       8       3       4
#3    3       1       8       3       4
#4    4       3       3       3       4
#5    5       1       2       4       3
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dataA %>% 
     mutate(across(-Name, ~ replace(., . > 4, 
          dataB[[str_replace(cur_column(), 'A', 'B')]])))
#  Name DataA_1 DataA_2 DataA_3 DataA_4
#1    1       4       8       3       5
#2    2       1       8       3       4
#3    3       1       8       3       4
#4    4       3       3       3       4
#5    5       1       2       4       3
```

#### data

```
dataA <- structure(list(Name = 1:5, DataA_1 = c(4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 1L), DataA_2 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 2L), DataA_3 = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L), DataA_4 = c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

dataB <- structure(list(DataB_1 = 1L, DataB_2 = 8L, DataB_3 = 3L, DataB_4 = 5L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's exactly a solution like the second one that I'm looking for. However, when I try it by replacing my data in your function, it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it's because I have a data frame constructed by the function ``read.csv2``and not a matrix as you. Sorry if it it's a stupid question, I'm kind of new in this.

Comment: @datascientist07 can you check if it is a data.frame ie `str(dataA)`, `str(dataB)`.  I assume that it should have worked

Comment: @datascientist07 i forgot to specify `library(stringr)`

Comment: @datascientist07 what is the `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: @datascientist07 I would suggest to show the `dput` i.e. `dput(head(dataA))` and `dput(dataB)`. With `dataB`, I assume it is a one row dataset

Comment: Yes, I previously installed the package and downloaded the library. And yes is a ``data.frame``. The error warning is : Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x replacement has length zero
ℹ Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.

Comment: the version is ‘1.0.4’. Adding ``dput``
 partially resolved the problem. However, in my case I have a lot more of data (a lot more that 5 rows) and when I use ``dput``, it only keeps 5 rows